# Detaching EF entities from DB context, removing their relations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, serialization

```
    public List<PRODUCT> GetProductsByProductcategory(decimal productCategoryKey)
    {
        DBEntities ctx = new DBEntities();
        List<PRODUCT> productList = ctx.PRODUCT.Where(p => p.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_KEY == productCategoryKey).ToList();
        return productList;
    }
```

Is there any way to detach each PRODUCT-entity from the ctx instance, thus removing their relations to other entities? Or any other smart way to remove the related entities. My problem is that i cant serialize entities with relations. Its resulting in a circular reference exception. My current solution is to use `ctx.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false` which works. But if i do it like that i wont get any lazy loading. Help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What format are you attempting to serialize your entities into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are serializing to JSON, I would recommend using the [Json.NET library from James Newton-King](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). You can turn off the relations from being serialized. Below is the serialization method that I am using with the ReferenceLooping turned off.

```
 public static string Serialize(object model)
 {
     var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                     {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                     };
     return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.None, settings);
 }
```

Comment: I guess this should work, but last time i tried json.net i got a stackoverflow every time i tried to serialize something. Are you sure the relations are removed, and not serialized as well?

Comment: Yes, in my experience they have been removed. If you really wanted to make sure, you could map your EF entity to another new class that excludes the relations completely using http://automapper.org and then serialize that new class.